# The alien who could duplicate himself

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

I'm looking for the title of a science fiction book of the 80s (I think) about an good alien who came to Earth chasing a hostile race of reptilian aliens. I'm not sure but I think his name was Akor.

This Akor guy could create unlimited copies of himself.
And a bloody fight happens between multiple Akors and the reptilian aliens. I think he meets an earthling woman who helps him on his mission.

The bad guys weren't so much the reptilian conspiracy type but rather lizard-headed humanoid reptiles.

The good guy Akor was similar to humans and I think he was blond.

*Update: This may be relevant: I don't know if it was a translation, but the book was in Spanish.